# CE 1.8.1 taxes applied incorrectly

Tags: configuration, price, tax

I need some help with some tax settings.
I've created a tax rule with 19% tax rate for Germany. It applies for retail customer tax class.
Not logged in customers are set to retail customer tax class.

Shipping origin is set to Germany.

I want to display both prices without and with taxes.
But no matter what settings I try... and I am trying and researching for hours already... I don't get it right. It always either looks like:
- Both prices are the same, showing the catalog price (which I enter including taxes due to German law)
- The price without taxes shows the catalog price, the price with taxes shows the price plus 19%.

What it needs to look like is: The price without taxes should show the catalog price -19% and the price with taxes should show the catalog price.

Obviously I put my tax setting catalog price to 'including taxes', although I have tried it with and without and with all alternations in the other settings.

I also kept clearing the cache in between attempts.

I am at the end of my wits, how exactly do I make Magento calculate the price excluding tax from the price including tax which I enter in the backend?

Comment: Can you post your code so we can we can see what you are using?

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your tax settings. And please describe WHERE you want to have the price shown (prefered with a screen shot)